# Backup from SP 2013 on SQL 2014 to be restored on SP 2013 on SQL 2012

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql

I need to backup a SP 2013 site with SQL 2014 to be restored on SP 2013 with SQL 2012. I currently have a content DB backup but it is not working because of the different versions. Will it work if i took a backup from SP Site itself using powershell? Do I have any other alternatives?

Comment: Can both farm access the both sql server?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you try to restore using PowerShell, it would throw exception. For a successful restoration both source and destination Config database version must be the same. To have the same Config DB versions you must have the same SQL Server version on both servers.

In your case the source DB is SQL 2014 and the destination DB is SQL 2012. Even restoring using PowerShell will not work here.

Answer (score 0):

As long as SharePoint build numbers are same on both farm, you should be able to back-up/restore the site collection, irrespective of SQL server versions.

You check buildversion number using:

- Go to `Central Administration > System Settings > Manage servers in your farm (/_admin/FarmServers.aspx)`

Or

- Hit SharePoint command-line with `(get-spfarm).buildversion`